# Can I tell the gpg-agent to never ask me for a password?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, svn, gnupg, gpg-agent

I am working with a remote SVN repo every day, running on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. But I don't want to enter the SVN sever password every time I update or commit. So I enabled the GPG password store like this:

```
$ cat ~/.subversion/config
[auth]
password-stores = gpg-agent
store-passwords = yes
```

I start the gpg-agent in my WSL environment like this:

```
# Start gpg-agent, if not running already
ps -ef | grep gpg-agent | grep -v grep > /dev/null || eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=`gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket | tr -d '\n' && echo -n ::`
```

This works all fine, the GPG agent remembers my SVN password and asks me only once a day in the morning when I boot the machine and connect to the repo the first time (via VS Code). However, I don't want it to ask me every day again. Is there a way to tell the GPG agent to remeber my passwords forever?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, but it only works in Linux desktop environments, not WSL.

If you use the `pinentry-gtk3` package and  you're using a desktop environment that supports a libsecret-compatible DBus service (e.g., gnome-keyring), then you can save the password using that service by checking the box.  However, because WSL doesn't start a full desktop environment with the requisite services (or DBus, for that matter), there's not really a way to use it without extensive customization.

You could try looking into alternate pinentry implementations which save the password elsewhere, but of the ones shipped by default in Debian and Ubuntu, I believe only `pinentry-gtk3` is capable of saving the password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, too bad it''s not an option for WSL :(